# Alternative to has_many_polymorphs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, associations

I've been trying to use the has_many_polymorphs plugin with rails 3 but I get this error that I have no idea how to resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773379/how-do-i-patch-this-error-that-has-many-polymorphs-plugin-is-giving-me

I'm thinking of switching to some other solution to solve what I'm trying to do. I can probably use three different join tables with has_many through associations. Are there any other alternative options I have for generating the functionality that the has_many_polymorphs plugin provides?

Answer (score 0):

why you go for the plug-in it can be achieved by rails polymorphic associations see section 2.9 polymorphic associations on the given link [Rails Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

and i think there is no need for double sided polymorphism we can achieved it by simple polymorphic associations.

Comment: see this they have achieved double sided polymorohic association through some other means may be this can help you [many-to-many polymorphic](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/203838)